# BulkCopy and Collation from two Databases

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, collation

I have **two different databases**, one has `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS Collation` and the other `Modern_Spanish_CI_AS`,

I obtain the data from de source

```
Select [DATA1] collate database_default as cal_Key,
       [DATA2] collate database_default as telephone from [TableName]
```

After I **create** a new table in the database destination, like this

```
Create table TEMPO_XXX 
(cal_key varchar(20) COLLATE database_default not null,
telephone varchar(40) COLLATE database_default not null)
```

I use **ColumnMapping**, like this

```
sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("cal_Key", "cal_Key");
sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("telephone", " telephone ");
```

But always obtain the same Message:

> The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination

Answer (score 1):

The destination columnmapping is [case sensitive](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/94135/sqlbulkcopy-column-mappings-case-sensitivity)

Change your mapping to sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("cal_Key", "cal_key");

Also remove the spaces from " telephone "